# User date range input against a series of date ranges in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-range

I need to search a user's date range input against a series of date ranges in a MySQL table.

**Perhaps an example might explain this better.** Let's say I have a "Hotel" database with a "Rates" table. One row is for "Fall," from *September 1 to November 30*, and another is "Winter," from *December 1 to March 30* with additional columns in there as well. A guest is booking a room that overlaps two rates. He'll be there for Thanksgiving and leaving in early December. That'll cover two separate rates. I need to run a search that returns every "Rate" row that's within the guest's stay.

This only works if a guest's booking is completely WITHIN ONE (and only one) rate:

```
SELECT * FROM 'rates' WHERE start < $guestArrive AND end > $guestDepart
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are start and end dates mutually exclusive? can you do this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'rates' 
WHERE 
    (start <= $guestArrive AND $guestArrive <= end)
    OR
    (start <= $guestDepart and $guestDepart <= end)
```

or clearer:

```
SELECT * FROM 'rates' 
WHERE 
    ($guestArrive BETWEEN start AND end)
    OR
    ($guestDepart BETWEEN start AND end)
```